# Why is this server tag throwing an error after site upgrade?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, kentico

I've upgraded my kentico 6 site to the latest hotfix from version 6.0.4297.

We have a custom web part that has the following layout code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/CMSWebParts/Terradon/eventcalendar.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="CMSWebParts_Terradon_eventcalendar" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="TRD" Namespace="Terradon" %>
<div class="Calendar">
    <TRD:CustomCalendar font-size="11px" ID="calItems" Runat="server" titleformat="MonthYear" font-family="Arial" Width="249" CellPadding="5" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#ffffff" EnableViewState="true" OnVisibleMonthChanged="calItems_VisibleMonthChanged" OnDayRender="calItems_DayRender" OnPreRender="calitems_PreRender" OnSelectionChanged="calItems_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Day">
        <TitleStyle font-bold="true" font-size="14px" BorderColor="#ffffff" BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#222222"></TitleStyle>
        <NextPrevStyle ForeColor="#222222"></NextPrevStyle>
        <DayStyle BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#ffffff" BackColor="#e6e3de"></DayStyle>
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#820912" ForeColor="#ffffff"></TodayDayStyle>
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#444444" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="true" ></SelectedDayStyle>
    </TRD:CustomCalendar>
</div>
<div class="CalendarList">
    <asp:Panel cssclass="CalendarTitle" id="calendarWrap" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="calendarTitle" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Hyperlink ID="calendarViewMoreLink" runat="server" CssClass="CalendarViewMoreLink" Text="View Events"/>
    </asp:Panel>

        <cms:CMSRepeater ID="repEventList" runat="server" Visible="true" OrderBy="EventDate ASC" ZeroRowsText="There are currently no events." StopProcessing="false" EnableViewState="false" OnItemCreated="repEventList_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="repEventList_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
        </cms:CMSRepeater>
    <div class="EventDetail">
            <cms:CMSRepeater ID="repEvent" runat="server" Visible="false" StopProcessing="true"             EnableViewState="false" />
    </div>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The code worked fine in the old version of the site and even works fine on a local instance of Kentico with the latest hotfix. Since the upgrade I get the following error:

```
[Error loading the WebPart 'TerradonCalendar' of type 'TerradonCalendar'] 
Unknown server tag 'TRD:CustomCalendar'
```

Comment: Well, without more information I would say there is no custom control named `CustomCalendar` in the `Terradon` namespace. (Did it get moved/renamed/refactored in some other way?) Was something not deployed correctly?

Comment: I'm checking now. The layout code is in `eventcalendar.ascx` with an `eventcalendar.ascx.cs` for the backend code.

Comment: You were correct, the file was deleted during the migration/upgrade. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without more information I would say there is no custom control named CustomCalendar in the Terradon namespace.

It's possible that the custom control was refactored, moved, or renamed; or the assembly was not deployed correctly.